# How to create category product page in WordPress?

Tags: woocommerce, themes, categories

I need to change the look of the WooCommerce product category page. The problem is that most divs etc are in an include/wc-template-functions.php file. How can I create a file in my theme that I design according to my requirements but with the category page features?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the templates for WooCommerce. Below version 3.0 you could have made a new file in your themes folder under `/woocommerce/archive-product.php`
but in version 3+ * This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php.` Read more at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/